# Will this printer be good enough to make prototyping models?

Tags: extruder, 3d-models, 3d-design, printer-building

I'm new to the 3D printing world, but I've been doing some research over the past couple weeks.

I need a printer that is decent enough to make prototypes using simple 3D software (I use Blender for 3D models, but won't mind suggestions there also). The prototypes are for cases to hold small electronic components and will be generally  around 2*4*4 inches. They will meet to be sturdy enough to hold and run screws through etc. I'm probably going to do about 1000 models before getting the right one and creating enough prototypes.

I'm fairly good with electronics and should be able to put it together easily.

I've generally heard mixed reviews about different printer sets and I don't have the budget to get one of the higher end models.

Found this little number on Amazon :
[REPRAPGURU] DIY RepRap Prusa I3 3D Printer Kit With Molded Plastic Parts USA Company [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01E06IHJ0/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_tai_PgmYxb6DMARET](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01E06IHJ0)

Given the pieces of requirements, do you see this working for what I'm looking to do? AND is blender going to be the easiest way to get prototyping models onto this thing or are there easier free software?

Comment: Your question about the printer may be a bit too broad for this forum. I suggest that you perform a general search for that model, especially videos on YouTube, to see what others with experience will say, and use that as guidelines for your objective.  Blender will NOT be a good choice for your goal. There are many more free programs which will be easier to learn and better suited. Consider looking at OpenSCAD if you can code, also TinkerCAD, and search for Free Parametric 3d Modeling Software for more choices.

Comment: Hi, FallenFate, and welcome to 3D printer SE. As @fred_dot_u mentions, your question is currently [too broad for this forum](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/asking), which means that there almost no limit to the kind of answers you will get (pretty much *every* 3D printer on the market should fulfill your criteria!). I will therefore put your question on hold for now to avoid users simply listing their favorite 3D printer and software. :) I encourage you to edit your question if you want to know anything more specific, and then vote for it to be reopened. Best of luck!

Comment: Please do not post multiple (unrelated) questions in one single question.